# Almacenar y actualizar una variable en C

Tags: c

¡Hola!

Estoy intentando leer y hacer ping a una serie de direcciones IP. Éstas aparecen listadas en un fichero .txt externo, una encima de la otra y separadas por un salto de línea.

Mi intención es la de leer este archivo línea por línea, realizando ping a cada una de las IP's y extrayendo su tiempo medio de respuesta. Para eso tengo la función "media" implementada, que funciona retornándome dicha cifra como entero.

Lo que pretendo hacer es lograr almacenar ÚNICAMENTE la IP que ofrece mayor velocidad de respuesta, es decir, la que obtiene una cifra menor de reacción. Donde no sé cómo proceder es en cómo hacer para que, en esa lectura, si la IP que está siendo leída ofrece mejor respuesta sustituya la ya almacenada, para acabar almacenando la IP en cuestión y su velocidad media de respuesta y plasmarlas con un comando del tipo printf.

A continuación dejo la parte del código que contiene la parte que me resulta conflictiva, si necesitáis que os aclare algo más de la estructura global sólo tenéis que decírmelo:

```
respuestas = fopen("ip.txt", "r");
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), respuestas)) 
{ 
    int respuesta1 = media(line); 
    int respuesta2 = media(line); 
    if (respuesta1 < respuesta2) {             
        respuesta1 = respuesta2; 
        }         
        line;         
        stored = respuesta1; } 
    printf("Velocidad media: %d ms", stored); 
    printf("IP: %s", line);
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: En definitiva no planteas cual es tu duda, o que error obtienes, o que es lo que no entiendes, o...

Comment: Sí, me interesa saber cómo puedo almacenar una variable ("respuesta2" en el ejemplo) que, comparada con la anterior ("respuesta1"), si resulta ofrecer una cifra inferior en su operación ("media" en el ejemplo), tome ésta por válida ("stored") hasta que se termine de leer el fichero. Una vez leído este fichero, la IP (línea) de la que haya extraído la cifra inferior, debo almacenarlas, tanto la IP en sí como la cifra extraída, para operar con ello. Se me escapa el concepto que debo buscar para hacerlo funcionar de tal manera, o la sintaxis correcta para cuadrarlo.

Comment: En otras palabras:
Quiero leer una primera línea, extraer su tiempo medio, almacenar la línea y ese resultado en dos variables.
Leer la segunda línea, extraer el tiempo medio; si el tiempo medio es inferior al anterior, almacenar ambos - si no, continuar con los anteriores.

Hasta acabar de leer el archivo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu código, respuesta1 y respuesta2 son iguales aparentemente, ya que media(line) reciben de fgets la misma cadena de texto, piensa un poco en cómo funciona el bucle en cada iteracion. Para lograr lo que quieres debemos pensar de otra forma. almacenamos tanto respuesta como line en alguna variable.

```
respuestas = fopen("ip.txt", "r");
// pongamos una respuesta muy alta, si es necesario se cambia
int respuesta = 2000000000;
char ip[81] = {0};

while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), respuestas)) 
{ 
    int temp = media(line);  
    if (temp < respuesta) {             
        respuesta = temp;
        strcpy(ip, line);
        }         
 } 
    printf("Velocidad media: %d ms", respuesta); 
    printf("IP: %s", ip);
```

sin probar el código no sé si habrá algún error, pero al menos espero que te empuje en el camino correcto. Por cierto no sé si el operador sizeof te va a dar el tamaño correcto, quizas debas pensar en strlen() mas un espacio adicional para el caracter fin de cadena.